# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: What is the difference between environment and application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application with two clients: web and mobile (both android and iOS).

Should I create:

1. Two applications (web and mobile) with one environment each
2. One application with two environments (web and mobile)

What is the best option?

Answer (score 5):

Elastic Beanstalk (EB) is supposed to host one application. Therefore, if the different clients are two different applications (have different code, rather than just different "historical" version of the same code), they should be on two different EB applications, each with its own set of environments (you could have development, pre-production and produciton environments for example).

Answer (score 1):

Having been in this situation recently I think it's mostly personal preference.  I prefer to separate them out as much as possible in the case that service impacting maintenance that involves only one role wont interfere with the other role.

Example:  If you need to do maintenance on your web server role, you don't need to worry about your mobile app servers at all.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is no connections between the environments at the same application. right ? so I won't worry about my mobile app servers in both situations.